# Bootstrap list of thumbnails leaves empty columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to make a list of images with titles using Bootstrap 3.3.7, like an image gallery and I am getting this [weird behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F82Bg.jpg)

I am using an unordered list-group and for every image a list-group-item:

```
<section>
    <div class="content container">
        <div class="control row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Upload</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group row">
        {{#each pictures}}
                    <li class="list-group-item col-md-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="{{path}}" alt="imagefail" style="width:100%">
                            <div>
                                <h3 style="">{{title}}</h3>
                                <button class="copyButton btn btn-primary btn-block"><i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#160Copy</button>
                                <button class="deleteButton btn btn-danger btn-block"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#160Delete</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
        {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

I tried using a `div.row` instead of unordered list and for every image a `div.col-md-3` and it has the same result:

```
<div class="row">
{{#each pictures}}
    <div class="list-group-item col-md-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
       ....
    </div>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

Do you know any solution that does not require using a row for every 4 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the height of the images and it will work fine.

```
<div class="row">
  {{#each pictures}}
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
          <img src="{{path}}" alt="imagefail" style="width:100%; height:200px">
      </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a million! Been spending the whole day figuring this out.

Comment: Privileged to help you. Thanks